# Configuring Route to allow dot as extension?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

Imagine the following:

client app, which no one has control over, calls Web API methods but each of these methods ends in extensions such as :

```
/api/{controller}/{method}.ab
```

How is it possible to configure the ASP.NET web API, for a *specific* controller, to allow extensions for the method being called but also allow the existing default controllers to continue working?

For instance if we have a method call `GetCustomer`, the client app will call `GetCustomer.ab` but want that call to be routed to `GetCustomer` which is the method in the controller "Customer", so something like this:

```
http://fake.com/api/SmallService/GetCustomer.ab
```

`SmallService` is the specific controller.

There are other controllers but only want to apply this type of routing to a specific controller.

Enabling the RAMMFAR is not an option either (`RunAllManagedModulesForRequests`) due to performance and security reasons too.

This is for ASP.NET Web API 2 running on .NET 4.6