# ASP.NET MVC route with .asp extension

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

EDIT:  The 'duplicates' are not working - not sure why exactly.

I need to be able to support an ASP.NET WebApi (v5.2.3.0) route that looks like this:

```
https://example.com/orders/orders.asp
```

It's for a 3rd party device to be able to interact with my system.  I've tried messing around with the RouteConfig like this:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Orders",
            routeTemplate: "api/orders.asp",
            defaults: new { controller = "OrderConfirm", action = "Get", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

But I always get a 404 error.  I've messed around with the "Route" decoration, like this:

```
[Route("api/orders.asp")]
```

Controller code:

```
public class OrdersConfirmController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        string orderContent = "blah, blah, blah";
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, string.Empty);
        response.Content = new StringContent(orderContent, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");
        return response;
    }
}
```

But still the 404 errors.

Ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Routes with "File Extensions"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255876/asp-net-mvc-routes-with-file-extensions)

Comment: The 404 errors from your testing, or from the 3rd party device?

Comment: REST client simulating the request that the device would send.

Comment: You have in route table "api/orders.asp" but there is no in example "api" so what url do you want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configuring Route to allow dot as extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40561302/configuring-route-to-allow-dot-as-extension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new route at the top of route table

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "Orders",
      routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}.asp"
);
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "DefaultApi",
      routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
      defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

To `OrdersConfirmController` add attribute:

```
[RoutePrefix("Orders")]
public class OrdersConfirmController : ApiController
```

and for action

```
[Route("orders.asp")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
```

Also to allow dot in URL you need to add this to web.config

```
<system.webserver>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

Now you can reach resourse by `http://example.com/Orders/orders.asp`

Comment: It was the web.config changes that did it!  Thank you @MegaTron

Comment: Glad to have been of help :)